# php function sometimes pushing arrays other times objects

Tags: php

I have an app which i'm making a HTTP request via PHP to retrieve some XML data. I'm then taking a string in that data, splitting it by spaces (`" "`) and pushing it into a new array. I'm then taking an existing array and de-duping it against this new array using the function `array_diff`. Here is my code below:

```
 // THIS ARRAY IS MUCH LONGER BUT HAVE JUST PUT IN A FEW WORDS
$stopwords = array("a", "about", "above", "above", "across", "after", "afterwards", "again"); 

// this is my XML call
$test = simplexml_load_file('https://some-xml-endpoint.com/endpoint');

// defining a blank array where I want the result to go
$mappedWordsObj = [];

for($i = 0;$i < count($test->data);$i++) {

    // if I echo this it returns me a string with no quotes (sometimes the quotes would be in there and I thought this may have been the issue)
    $comment = chop(strtolower($test->data[$i]->comments));

    // here I split the comment into an array by spaces 
    $wordsArray = explode(' ', $comment);

    //here I compare my new array of words with the stopwords I want removed from the wordsArray
    $arr_1 = array_diff($wordsArray, $stopwords);

    // here I push into the $mappedWordsObj array
    array_push($mappedWordsObj, $arr_1);

}

// here I push to the DOM the result to see how my array looks
echo json_encode($mappedWordsObj);
```

My issue is that in the resulting `$mappedWordsObj` array, I expect all the array items to be arrays themselves that contain the words but some of the items are getting inserted in the `$mappedWordsObj` as arrays with the words and others as objects with properties whos values are the words. Here is a snippet of the data returned:

```
{"0":"i","1":"just","2":"want","4":"switch","6":"existing","7":"t-mobile","8":"pay","13":"ee","14":"pay","15":"monthly.","16":"i","17":"don't","18":"want","20":"new","21":"phone!","23":"page","24":"does","26":"tell","31":"this!"},{"0":"just","2":"option","4":"'sim","5":"only'","9":"'radio","10":"button'","11":"forced","12":"selection."},
["voice","recignition"],
["testing","ol"],
{"0":"can't","1":"think","4":"i","7":"simple","9":"easy"},{"2":"instead","3":"lol"},
["n\/a"],
["great","website"],
```

I'd like to just have an array of arrays so can anyone please tell me where i've gone wrong?

Cheers

Comment: json_encode... a numeric array will be encoded as an array, a key => value array (assoc) will end up as an object, after your array_diff try `$arr_1 = array_values($arr_1);` which will give you a numeric array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `json_encode`, it will convert PHP arrays to either JSON arrays or JSON objects. Which one is output depends completely on the array keys in the PHP array. For PHP arrays with sequential, numeric indexes starting at 0, the JSON output will be an array. For PHP arrays with any other indexes, the JSON output will be an object.

The `array_diff` produces an array where the indexes are not sequential in some cases. You can use `array_values` to reindex the result before appending it to your output array.

```
array_push($mappedWordsObj, array_values($arr_1));
```

---

Side note - `array_push` actually isn't necessary here. You can use

```
$mappedWordsObj[] = array_values($arr_1);
```

[The `array_push` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) actually recommends doing it this way when you're only appending one item to the array. But, it's a pretty small optimization, so if `array_push` looks better to you, never mind. :)

Comment: That fixed it, thanks for the explanation. WIll mark correct in 5 mins

Comment: @Dale sure enough.